# Автоматизирование таблиц при помощи jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, таблицы

Имеется таблица на сайте и хотелось бы её как-то автоматизировать [image: Таблица]

Таблица написана на обычном html. Но продукции в ней довольно много и на каждой категории товара другая таблица. Также нумерация товаров идёт так, на первой странице Арматура отсчёт от 1 до 41. На следующей странице Катанка идёт с 41 до 60 и так далее. Хотелось бы чтобы нумерация ID выставлялась автоматически на каждый товар.

Имеется скрипт который работает, но не совсем то, чего я хочу добиться.

```
function row_id ( num = 1 )
 {
  var table = $('table'); // сюда айди или класс таблицы
  var td = table.children().children().not('tr:first-child').children('td:first-child');
  $(td).each(function(i,e){
    $(e).html(num + i);
  })
}
row_id(45);
```

При подключении к документу html, в скрипте значение row_id() нужно менять  вручную например если предыдущая страница кончилась на 44 то на этой нужно указать 45 и он автоматически выставит от 45 до последнего товара на этой странице.

Ещё было бы идеально чтобы можно было добавить товар в любое место таблицы.
Ссылка на сайт: https://metallcenter.uz/products/armatura_a3

Comment: В чем вы видите проблему данной задачи? Что пробовали уже сделать сами и что пошло не так?

Comment: function row_id ( num = 1 )
     {
      var table = $('table');
      var td = table.children().children().not('tr:first-child').children('td:first-child');
      $(td).each(function(i,e){
        $(e).html(num + i);
      })
    }
    row_id(45); (Этот код работает но не совсем то что я хотел. Тут нужно для каждой страницы подключать отдельный js так как на всех row_id нужно ставить вручную начиная с первого id) А проблема только в том что у меня не такие обширные знания в js.

Comment: в тело вопроса код разместите, а лучше предоставьте полноценный пример того как и что у вас работает. Если знаний недостаточно, возможно есть смысл обратиться ко фрилансерам.